# Retrieving device WiFi MAC address with iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uidevice

Our app is using device WiFiMAC address to uniquely identify a device. As per the
[Apple doumentation](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=8222013a) we shall start using identifierForVendor property of UIDevice but my app is strongly dependent on WiFi MAC address. At run time, app users look into device settings and fetch the WiFi Mac address and manually put them in some tool to enable some feature on server side. Has anyone retrieved the device WiFi MAC address with iOS 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was intentionally removed from the SDK in iOS 7. You can no longer retrieve the MAC address. [Techcrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/14/ios-7-eliminates-mac-address-as-tracking-option-signaling-final-push-towards-apples-own-ad-identifier-technology/) has one of several stories on it, and it was confirmed at WWDC.

Answer (score 0):

Use [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) and from command line run:
./ideviceinfo -k WiFiAddress