# How to get device Wifi address in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi

[image]

How to get a device wifi address programmtically in app? not mac address of the connected wifi.

[How can I programmatically get the MAC address of an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677530/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-mac-address-of-an-iphone)
Also checked this link which returning 02:00:00:00:00:00 as address

> Path to see in device
>
> Settings>General>About>Wifi address

See attached image for reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19820005/6124910

Comment: please follow the link that may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339089/can-the-iphone-sdk-obtain-the-wi-fi-ssid-currently-connected-to

Comment: @Abhay Singh Naurang SSID referred to connected wifi address. I need Device wifi address shown in the image